# how will I find odd elements from two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have one array

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {1,2};
```

how will I find the odd element in array

Comment: your question is incoherent, whats the second array  for ?

Comment: Sure you're looking for a hint to find odd numbers (1,3,5,...) or is it something else?

Comment: i think he is trying to compare the two array's and find the unique numbers among them. so according to his example provided the answer must be 3....

Comment: That's an odd definition of odd.

Comment: -1 for extreme laziness of question poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int[] longArray = { 1, 3, 2 };
    int[] shortArray = { 1, 2 };

    //Check which array is longer, if b longer than a then swap

    for (int x:longArray){
        set.add(x);
    }
    for (int x:shortArray){
        if (set.contains(x))
           set.remove(x);
    }
    //odd numbers
    for (Object i:set.toArray())
        System.out.println(i+",");
```

I put two answers for the voting, the previous is nested loops and might be slow for very long arrays. In the next solution some might dont prefer the TreeSet.

Comment: hey i tried to take List instead of set but I am getting runtime Exception IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: The exception occurs in the remove method, since it takes an "index" if you're passing in int (which is the case here), if you want to use remove like the one in Sets then you will need to pass an Object say Integer, but in this case it will not work, because Integer(1)!=Integer(1). 
Back to the main point, Lists allows duplicates. Sets don't. So aside from the "remove implementation" you better stick to Sets because of the duplicates as well.

Comment: This won't work! How it will find the odd element if it is present in shorter array ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[] longArray = { 1, 3, 2 };
    int[] shortArray = { 1, 2 };

    //Check which array is longer, if b longer than a then swap

    boolean found = false;
    int odd = 0;

    for (int i : longArray) {
        for (int j : shortArray) {
            if (i == j)
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found)
            odd = i;
        found = false;
    }
    System.out.println(odd);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Set Comparisons, have a look at [java-is-there-an-easy-quick-way-to-and-or-or-xor-together-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393968/java-is-there-an-easy-quick-way-to-and-or-or-xor-together-sets)

This SO question was talking in terms of the Set interface, but the List interface also inherits the relevant methods from Collection, so copying your arrays to ArrayList objects makes it easy.

If you want to keep it purely at the native array level, you might want to do something like:

```
 public int[] findOddElement(int[] fromArray, int[] secondArray){
  int[] result = new int[fromArray.length];
  int resPointer = 0;
  for (int i = 0;i < fromArray.length;i++){
   boolean notFound = true;
   for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
    if (fromArray[i] == secondArray[j]) {
     notFound = false;
     break;
    }
   }
   if (notFound){
    result[resPointer] = fromArray[i];
    resPointer++;
   }
  }
  if (resPointer > 0 && resPointer < fromArray.length ) {
   int[] newResult = new int[resPointer];
   for (int i = 0;i < resPointer; i++) {
    newResult[i] = result[i];

   }
   return newResult;
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: ArrayList does not implement the Set interface. List does not extend the Set interface. List and Set are two different extensions of the Collection interface.

Comment: Yes, my bad: The features used in the XOR discussion are inherited by both Set and List from the Collection interface. Edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make a loop for each array item. Those for which `item & 1 == 1` are odd.

Comment: Probably, you mean item % 2 == 1

Comment: It was a typo, I meant `&`, not `%`.